# Changing NotesTeX page layout

Tags: geometry, layout

I came across [Aditya](https://ctan.org/pkg/notestex)'s beautiful **NotesTeX** template, to which I wish to change the page layout a bit.
The `NotesTeX.sty` file includes a `geometry` package command that sets up the page layout.

What I want is

- to increase the `inner` attribute to 0.05\page width,
- narrow down the `textwidth` to 0.55\page width,
- and widen up the `marginparsep` to 0.05\page width.

Am I missing any value to be changed together with these 3?
When compiling on overleaf, I get a handful of
`Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines xx-xx` in the log file, and a few `Marginpar on page x moved`.

I am a novice TeX user (although I did dig down to the template settings), and would like to make sure that my changes won't cause some harder errors when in the publishing stage of my project.

As it stands now, the settings are as follows:

```
\geometry{
paperheight=845pt,paperwidth=597pt,
marginparsep=.02\paperwidth,
marginparwidth=.23\paperwidth,
inner=.05\paperwidth,
voffset=-1in,
headheight=.02\paperheight,
headsep=.03\paperheight,
footskip=20pt,
textheight=.84\paperheight,
textwidth=.64\paperwidth
    }
```

with the page layout as in picture:
[image]